# Value of variable is always undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

When I try this code, the value of the variable 'active_field' is always 'undefined', no matter what item I click first.

```
$('#kompetenz1').click(function(){
    alert(active_field);
    if (active_field) { 
        $('.content' + active_field + ', #kompetenz'+ active_field +' img').hide();
    }
    $('.content1, #kompetenz1 img').show();
    var active_field = 1;
});

$('#kompetenz2').click(function(){
    if (active_field) { 
        $('.content' + active_field + ', #kompetenz'+ active_field +' img').hide();
    }
    $('.content2, #kompetenz2 img').show();
    var active_field = 2;
});

$('#kompetenz3').click(function(){
    if (active_field) { 
        $('.content' + active_field + ', #kompetenz'+ active_field +' img').hide();
    }
    $('.content3, #kompetenz3 img').show();
    var active_field = 3;
});

$('#kompetenz4').click(function(){
    if (active_field) { 
        $('.content' + active_field + ', #kompetenz'+ active_field +' img').hide();
    }
    $('.content4, #kompetenz4 img').show();
    var active_field = 4;
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Another one of variable hoisting.

Comment: `active_field` isn't global.

Comment: @MinusFour thank you, that was the answer! It works now!